# Redraw circle - python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this bit of code here:

```
from tkinter import *


class player():
    def __init__(self, radius, xcoordinate = 0, ycoordinate = 0):
        self.xcoordinate = xcoordinate
        self.ycoordinate = ycoordinate
        self.radius = radius

    def moveRight(self, event):
        self.xcoordinate += 25
        self.draw()
        print("Right key pressed")
        print("x: " + str(self.xcoordinate))

    def moveLeft(self, event):
        self.ycoordinate += 25
        self.draw()
        print("Left key pressed")
        print("y: " + str(self.ycoordinate))

    def draw(self):
        world = client()
        world.title("World")
        world.bind('<Right>', self.moveRight)
        world.bind('<Left>', self.moveLeft)        
        canvas = Canvas(world, width=200, height=200, borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0, bg="black")
        canvas.grid()
        canvas.draw_player(self.xcoordinate, self.ycoordinate, self.radius, fill="blue", width=4)
        world.mainloop()

class client(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def draw_player(self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
        return self.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)

    Canvas.draw_player = draw_player    

p1 = player(50)
p1.draw()
```

The problem is that whenever I press the right or left arrow keys, it calls the draw() method. The draw() method constructs a new client object and etc.

So you end up opening multiple windows each with a circle with different x and y coordinates. How do I make this such that when I call draw() it only edits the x and y coordinates and **redraws** the circle on the same window?

Please no suggestions to use pygame, my IDE gets errors when I try to import the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that

> redraws the circle on the same window

means moving the circle, and does not mean drawing a second circle in the same space.  Use the move() function for a canvas object to do this http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm .  Note that you have to save a reference to the object to be moved.  Also your moveLeft() function doesn't.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, master, radius, xcoordinate=100, ycoordinate=100):
        self.master=master
        self.xcoordinate = xcoordinate
        self.ycoordinate = ycoordinate
        self.radius = radius
        self.master.title("World")
        self.master.bind('<Right>', self.moveRight)
        self.master.bind('<Left>', self.moveLeft)        
        self.draw()  ## called once

    def moveRight(self, event):
        self.canvas.move(self.oval_id, 25, 0)
        print("Right key pressed")
        print("x: " + str(self.xcoordinate))

    def moveLeft(self, event):
        self.canvas.move(self.oval_id, 0, 25)
        print("Left key pressed")
        print("y: " + str(self.ycoordinate))

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.master, width=200, height=200,
                 borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0, bg="black")
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.oval_id=self.canvas.create_oval(self.xcoordinate-self.radius,
                                        self.ycoordinate-self.radius, 
                                        self.xcoordinate+self.radius,
                                        self.ycoordinate+self.radius,
                                        fill="red")

master=Tk()
p1 = Player(master, 50)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: This was really helpful. I'm just wondering what self.draw() does in the constructor. Also, is naming it oval_id necessary? Could you just do a function that returns self.canvas.create_oval(etc)

Comment: "what self.draw() does in the constructor"--> comment it out and see what happens.  You have to save a reference to objects, so it has to be self.something otherwise the reference is garbage collected when the function exits.  The same for the reference to the Canvas object.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last thing. I'm relatively new to class structures and stuff. Why did you have to set "master" in the paramter list for the class Player? Since master is an object, can't it just be passed in through self?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  "master" has to be able to be seen through out the class so it can be passed to the Canvas class in the function draw().  Just "master" instead of "self.master" would only exist in the "__init__" function.  And you could just do self.master=Tk() and run master.mainloop() in the "__init__" function, but it is usually instantiated outside of the class so it can be passed to other classes when there is more than one class.

Answer (score 4):

The code can be simplified by passing the move parameters to a single function.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class player():
    def __init__(self, master, radius, xcoordinate=100, ycoordinate=100):
        self.master=master
        self.xcoordinate = xcoordinate
        self.ycoordinate = ycoordinate
        self.radius = radius
        self.master.title("World")
        self.master.bind('<Right>', partial(self.move_oval, 25, 0))
        self.master.bind('<Left>', partial(self.move_oval, -25, 0))
        self.master.bind('<Up>', partial(self.move_oval, 0, -25))
        self.master.bind('<Down>', partial(self.move_oval, 0, 25))
        self.draw()  ## called once

    def move_oval(self, x, y, event):
        self.canvas.move(self.oval_id, x, y)
        print("key pressed", x, y)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.master, width=200, height=200,
                 borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0, bg="black")
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.oval_id=self.canvas.create_oval(self.xcoordinate-self.radius,
                                        self.ycoordinate-self.radius, 
                                        self.xcoordinate+self.radius,
                                        self.ycoordinate+self.radius,
                                        fill="red")
master=Tk()
p1 = player(master, 50)
master.mainloop()
```